# Redbeanphp - Query securely with multiple conditions

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I have a list of users in my database, e.g. with firstname, lastname and company, which are all textfields. Now I have an autocomplete field where one can enter firstname, lastname and company to find a user that has a similar name or company name. I want to accomplish this with RedbeanPHP. Unfortunately the documentation doesn't explain how to implement multiple conditions into their "finder"-functions. Also the "exec"-function isnt explained very well, because there I don't know how to prepare values from a form into the manual statement.

Here is my solution that does find users when either firstname or lastname or company is entered:

```
        if (!empty($_POST['autocomplete'])) {
            $userListbyFirstname = R::find( 'user', ' firstname LIKE ?', [ '%' . $_POST['autocomplete'] . '%' ] );
            $userListbyLastname = R::find( 'user', ' lastname LIKE ?', [ '%' . $_POST['autocomplete'] . '%' ] );
            $userListbyCompany = R::find( 'user', ' company LIKE ?', [ '%' . $_POST['autocomplete'] . '%' ] );
            $userRbList = array_merge($userListbyFirstname, $userListbyLastname, $userListbyCompany);
            $userList = array();
            foreach ($userRbList as $userRb) {
                $userList[] = $userRb['firstname'] . ' ' . $userRb['lastname'] . ' ' . (!empty($userRb['company']) ? $userRb['company'] : '');
            }
            return json_encode($userList);
        }
        else
        {
            return json_encode(array());
        }
```

When someone enters "John Williams" it returns an empty array, even if there is an database entry for it. I would know how to do it with plain php, but not how to accomplish, that those multiple fields can be searched together (= multiple conditions) with RedBeanPHP.

Comment: I suspect you are over estimating what the  `redbeanPHP` `find` function does. It takes the sql string and appends it to the generated SQL after the `WHERE` statement. Then it prepares the resulting `SQL` query string. So:  To match on first and last name use the SQL string:  `' firstname LIKE ? and  lastname LIKE ?'` as the SQL. The `where clause` can be a complex as you wish. The `exec` function is similar.

Comment: `$userRbList = R::find( 'user', ' (firstname LIKE ?) or (lastname LIKE ?) or (company LIKE ?)', [ '%' . $_POST['autocomplete'] . '%' ] );` doesn't work for example like expected

Comment: okay, thank you that works! if you want you can answer the question i'll give you a vote and mark it as top answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirements: Add multiple conditions to the `WHERE` clause when using the `redbeanPHP` `find function`.

The `find` function expects a valid `SQL` `WHERE` clause. It can be any valid SQL. Often, it is some multi column filter that is required.

Example: To match on `firstname` OR `lastname` OR `company`.

The SQL Query string will be something like:

```
' (firstname LIKE ?) or (lastname LIKE ?) or (company LIKE ?)'
```

Now, there are three `placeholders` so when the query is executed then it needs three runtime values in the `parameters` array.

Example:

```
array( '%'. $_POST['firstname'] .'%',
       '%'. $_POST['lastname']  .'%',
       '%'. $_POST['company']   .'%' 
    )
```

Now, `redbeanPHP` takes the SQL `where` clause you have supplied and appends it to the generated query. It then `prepares` the resulting SQL which looks like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user
WHERE  (firstname LIKE ?) or (lastname LIKE ?) or (company LIKE ?);
```

It then executes the query using the array of runtime parameters you supply.

That is what:

```
R::find('user', 
        ' (firstname LIKE ?) or (lastname LIKE ?) or (company LIKE ?)',             
         array( '%'. $_POST['firstname'] .'%',
                '%'. $_POST['lastname']  .'%',
                '%'. $_POST['company']   .'%')
       );
```

Actually does.